# Авторизация на сайт через соц. сети

Tags: вконтакте, авторизация

Как сделать авторизацию на сайт так, чтобы можно было входить\регестрироваться через вконтакте, мейл.ру и т.д

Comment: Воспользуйтесь сервисом loginza. На сайте есть документация. [Логинза](http://loginza.ru/)
Позволяет работать со многими сервисами.

Comment: Главное не забывайте о безопасности такой авторизации. Вот вам [пример](http://youtu.be/q-oHLbYMJZg).

Answer (score 1):

Если Вам хочется получить почти готовое решение, имеющее множество модулей для разных cms и/или короткое и ясное API обратите внимание на продукт, который был недавно выкуплен Яндексом - [Loginza](http://loginza.ru/) - Open ID провайдер.

Comment: Крутая штука, и действительно, весьма просто подключается.

Comment: яша выкупил 0о 
блин чтобы мне такое сделать, дабы яша у меня его купил )

Answer (score 0):

OpenID — это открытая децентрализованная система, которая позволяет пользователю использовать единый аккаунт для аутентификации на множестве не связанных друг с другом сайтов, порталов, блогов и форумов([wiki](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Openid)). А [вот тут](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/webdev/93892/) вкратце описано внедрение.